# Java reflection updating the .class files

Tags: java, reflection

I just learned about the Java reflection capabilities and used it to successfully do the following :

1. Accessing public member function of a class
2. Setting public member functions of a class

My questions is when I do setting will my .class file get updated (I don't see that happening with the new set values)?

I see [Java Reflection Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), but I am not sure about the answer to my question. If the .class file should not be updated then how do we `RESET` the .class file to contain dynamic data  so that the program can keep using the new set of values and not the old set of values determined at compile time? Or this is just not possible?

Comment: The asnwer is: No. You have to serialize the class if you want your field values to be preserved.

Comment: I'm very, very confused. The question implies that reflection was used to somehow add a new method ("member function") using reflection, but that is not possible. You can use reflection to call a setter method and change the property value of an instance of a class. That has nothing at all to do with any .class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.class` is a compiled code (a transformation of your `.java`) this is a read only file for the `jvm`.

The `jvm` read the code of your `.class` and then the code live in the `jvm` memory. All reflection methods modify `in memory` code and never write it back to a `.class`.